# LaTeX used to compile a file, and now it doesn't, no error marked

Tags: errors

I had a fully functional code working, and when I compiled it I noticed that I had erased the `\tableofcontents`, so, I added it again, and suddenly stop compiling, now it doesn't compile not even if I erase the `\tableofcontets`.

No error message in log, but a few warnings. I'll leave the full code next:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oldfontcommands, openany]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{morefloats}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{dblfloatfix}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\selectlanguage{spanish}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[
breaklinks=true,colorlinks=true,
linkcolor=blue,urlcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,% PDF VIEW
%linkcolor=black,urlcolor=black,citecolor=black,% PRINT
bookmarks=true,bookmarksopenlevel=2]{hyperref}
\usepackage{geometry}
% PDF VIEW
 \geometry{total={210mm,297mm},
 left=25mm,right=25mm,%
 bindingoffset=0mm, top=25mm,bottom=25mm}
% PRINT
%\geometry{total={210mm,297mm},
%left=20mm,right=20mm,
%bindingoffset=10mm, top=25mm,bottom=25mm}

\OnehalfSpacing
%\linespread{1.3}

%%% CHAPTER'S STYLE
\chapterstyle{bianchi}
%\chapterstyle{ger}
%\chapterstyle{madsen}
%\chapterstyle{ell}
%%% STYLE OF SECTIONS, SUBSECTIONS, AND SUBSUBSECTIONS
\setsecheadstyle{\Large\bfseries\sffamily\raggedright}
\setsubsecheadstyle{\large\bfseries\sffamily\raggedright}
\setsubsubsecheadstyle{\bfseries\sffamily\raggedright}


%%% STYLE OF PAGES NUMBERING
%\pagestyle{companion}\nouppercaseheads 
%\pagestyle{headings}
%\pagestyle{Ruled}
\pagestyle{plain}
\makepagestyle{plain}
\makeevenfoot{plain}{\thepage}{}{}
\makeoddfoot{plain}{}{}{\thepage}
\makeevenhead{plain}{}{}{}
\makeoddhead{plain}{}{}{}


\maxsecnumdepth{subsection} % chapters, sections, and subsections are numbered
\maxtocdepth{subsection} % chapters, sections, and subsections are in the Table of Contents


%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%

\begin{document}

%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%
%   TITLEPAGE
%
%   due to variety of titlepage schemes it is probably better to make titlepage manually
%
%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%
\thispagestyle{empty}

{%%%
\sffamily
\centering
\Large


{\Huge Universidad de Guadalajara}\\

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\subfloat{
\includegraphics[width=8cm]{h.png}
}
\subfloat{
\includegraphics[width=6cm]{g.png}
}
\end{figure}
{\LARGE Centro Universitario de Ciencias Exactas e Ingenierías}\\
\vspace{1cm}
{\Large Licenciatura en Ingeniería en Comunicaciones y Electrónica.}\\
\vspace{0.5cm}
Ingeniería de Control
\vspace{0.5cm}

{\huge 
Godfrey Harold Hardy: \\Una introducción a los espacios de Hardy
}

{\large Carlos Enrique González Álvarez\\
Luis Omar Nuñez Romero\\
José de Jesús Jauregui Moran}\\
Equipo 6.\\
\vspace{1cm}
Profesor: Dr. Eduardo Ruiz Velazquez

\vspace{\fill}

8 marzo 2019

%%%
}%%%
\tableofcontents
\newpage



\section{List of Symbols}
\begin{longtable}{p{5mm} c p{120mm} }
\multicolumn{3}{l}{Mayúsculas}\\
\\
$\left< x,y \right>$ &  & Producto Interno, puede verse como la suma del cuadrado de los elementos de un vector.
\\
${x}^{*},\overline{x} $ &   & Complejo conjugado del vector o elemento x.
\\
${\left\| x \right\|}$ &   & Norma de un vector o matriz x.
\\
{trace[A]} &   & Función trace, es la suma de los elementos de la diagonal principal de una matriz A.
\\
$\in$ &   & Pertenece a...
\\
$\mathbb{C}$ &   & Conjunto de los números complejos.
\\
$\mathbb{R}$ &  & Conjunto de los números reales.
\\
:= & & Está definido como... 
\\
Re(s) &   &  Parte real de s
\\
$\overline{\sigma}$(A) &   & El valor singular más alto de A.
\\
I  &   & Matriz identidad.
\\
sup &   & Elemento supremo de un subconjunto A, es el mínimo valor de un conjunto P, que es mayor o igual a cada elemento de S.
\\
$\mathcal{L}_{2}(j\mathbb{R})$ &   & Espacio de Hilbert compuesto por funciones cuadradas integrables en {${\mathbb{C}}_{0}$}, incluyendo al $\infty$.
\\
$\mathcal{L}_{\infty}(j\mathbb{R})$ &  & Espacio de Hilbert compuesto por funciones limitadas a Re(s)=0, incluyendo al $\infty$.
\\
$\mathcal{H}_{2}$ &   & Subespacio de $\mathcal{L}_{2}(j\mathbb{R})$ con funciones analíticas en Re(s)>0 
\\
$\mathcal{H} _{\infty}$ &  & Subespacio de $\mathcal{L}_{\infty}(j\mathbb{R})$ con funciones analíticas en Re(s)>0.
\\
max &   & Maximum, punto en que una función alcanza su valor máximo.
\\

\end{longtable}


\chapter{Introducción}
\section{Control Robusto}
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
\includegraphics[scale=1]{a.png} 
    \label{fig1}
    \caption{Modelo generalizado de Control Robusto}
\end{figure}

La teoría de Control Robusto surge a partir de la inexactitud de los modelos de control convencionales, en los cuáles se representaba matemáticamente un sistema como un modelo único, muchas veces sin considerar partes del sistema que podrían no ser tan obvios a simple vista, por lo que el control robusto representa matemáticamente los sistemas como una familia de modelos que componen a un mismo sistema.
En la figura {\ref{fig1} se observa la generalización de los sistemas mediante el control robusto, en donde no sólo tenemos la señal de referencia y una salida del sistema, sino que también, de manera general, se toman en consideración los ruidos, la incertidumbre y otros sistemas que podrían, directa o indirectamente, afectar el sistema.

\section{Fundamentos matemáticos}
\subsection{Espacio Vectorial}
Un espacio vectorial es una estructura algebraica creada a partir de un conjunto no vacío, en la cuál están definidas ciertas operaciones como la suma, un producto escalar,     operaciones en las cuales, si se realizan entre dos objetos pertenecientes al mismo espacio vectorial, el resultado también pertenecerá al mismo espacio. A los elementos que conforman dicho espacio se les conoce como vectores.
\subsubsection{Subespacios vectoriales}
Un subespacio vectorial es un espacio vectorial más pequeño que existe dentro de otro, que cumple con ciertas características específicas, a la vez que con las características del espacio vectorial al que pertenece.
\subsubsection{Producto interno de espacios vectoriales}
Se define como producto interno a la sumatoria de un vector multiplicado por el complejo conjugado de otro. El producto interno de un solo vector, por ejemplo, es la suma del cuadrado de sus componentes, similar a lo que hacemos en álgebra lineal cuando se desea obtener la magnitud del vector.
El producto interno está dado por la siguiente fórmula:
\begin{equation}
 \left< x,y \right> = {x}^{*}y =\sum _{ i=1 }^{ n }{ \overline { { x }_{ i } } { y }_{ i } ,\quad \quad x,y\in { \mathbb{C} }^{ n } }  
\end{equation}

\subsubsection{Norma}
Dado que los vectores son representaciones de segmentos entre 2 puntos de un espacio, la norma se define como la distancia entre dichos puntos en línea recta. En $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ se le conoce como módulo de un vector, o magnitud. Se define de la siguiente manera:
\begin{equation}
{\left\| x \right\|}_{p     } = \sqrt[p]{{ \left< x \right>}^{p}}  \quad \quad \textrm{para 1 $\leqslant$  p  < $\infty$}
\end{equation}
*Nótese que cuando p tiende a $\infty$ la norma se puede definir como:
\begin{equation}
  { \left\| x \right\|  }_{ \infty  }:=\underset { 1\le i\le m }{ max } \left| { x }_{ i } \right| 
\end{equation}

\subsection{Espacios de funciones}
\subsubsection{Espacios de Banach}
Llamados así en honor al matemático polaco Stefan Banach, es un espacio de funciones de dimensiones infinta, en el cuál se cumple la definición de norma y se considera un espacio completo (es decir, que tiene la distancia entre 2 de sus componentes, o vectores que lo componen, es mayor que 0).
\subsubsection{Espacios de Hilbert}
\label{L2JR}
Es una generalización del espacio Euclídeo, que permite la aplicación de conceptos algebraicos a espacios con dimensiones infinitas, por lo que estos espacios tienen una norma, un producto interno definidos, se puede medir el ángulo entre 2 vectores, se puede proyectar un vector sobre otro, se cumple el teorema de Pitágoras, etc.\\
Cabe que mencionar que un espacio de Hilbert es un subespacio de un espacio de Banach.\\
Como está dado para espacios de dimensiones tanto finitas como infinitas, es más fácil definir su producto interno y su norma matricialmente de la siguiente manera:
\\a) Para dimensiones finitas:
\begin{equation}
\left< A,B \right> := trace[{A}^{*},B] =\sum _{ i=1 }^{ n }{ \sum _{ j=i }^{ m }{ { \overline { a }  }_{ ij }{ b }_{ ij } } \quad ,\quad \quad A,B\in \quad { C }^{ nxm } } 
\end{equation}
donde ${a}_{ij}$ y ${b}_{ij}$ son los componentes de las matrices A y B respectivamente, que tienen dimensiones nxm.
\\b) Para dimensiones infinitas:
\begin{equation}
\left< f,g \right> :=\int _{ a }^{ b }{ {f(t)}^{*}g(t)dt } \quad \quad
\textrm{Mejor conocido como el espacio ${\mathcal{L}}_{2}$[a,b]}
\end{equation}
\chapter{Espacios de Hardy}
\section{Espacio \textbf{${\mathcal{H}}_{2}$}}
${\mathcal{H}}_{2}$ es un subespacio de ${\mathcal{L}}_{2}(j\mathbb{R})$ (véase la definición \ref{L2JR}, sin embargo está delimitado únicamente a los números puramente imaginarios).\\
En ${\mathcal{H}}_{2}$ las funciones matriz F(s) son analíticas en Re(s)>0 (parte derecha del plano).\\
Su norma está dada por:\\\\
\begin{equation}
{\left\| F \right\|  }_{ 2 }^{ 2 }=\frac { 1 }{ 2\pi  } \int _{0} ^{\infty}{ trace[{F}^{*}(j\omega )F(j\omega )]d\omega  }  
\end{equation}
*Nótese que la norma está elevada al cuadrado, y la norma es bastante similar a la de ${\mathcal{L}}_{2}$, pero en función de la frecuencia, por lo tanto se tiene que: \\
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \label{fig2}
\includegraphics[scale=1]{b.png} 
    \caption{Relación entre espacios de funciones}
\end{figure}

\section{Espacio \textbf{${\mathcal{H}}_{\infty}$}}
Es un subespacio de ${\mathcal{L}}_{\infty} (j\mathbb{R})$, con funciones que son analíticas en Re(s)>0, es decir, en la mitad derecha del plano. Se define como el valor singular más alto que alcanza en frecuencia la función $F(j\omega)$
\begin{equation}
 { \left\| F \right\|  }_{ \infty  }:=\underset { \omega \in \mathbb{R}\  }{ sup } \bar { \sigma  } [F(j\omega )]
\end{equation}
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \label{fig3}
\includegraphics[scale=1]{c.png} 
    \caption{${ \left\| G \right\|  }_{ \infty  }$ is el valor pico más grande de los valores singulares de $G(j\omega)$, circulado en rojo.}
\end{figure}

\chapter{Aplicaciones en control}
\section{Estabilidad de sistemas}
Supóngase un sistema de la siguiente forma:
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \label{fig4}
\includegraphics[scale=1]{d.png} 
    \caption{Configuración estándar de lazo cerrado.}
\end{figure}
Suponiendo que conocemos las señales de perturbación y de entrada (r,n,d y ${d}_{i}$) y que la función matriz u es propia y está bien definida. Entonces podemos simplificar el sistema de la siguiente manera:\\
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \label{fig5}
\includegraphics[scale=1]{e.png} 
    \caption{Simplificación del diagrama de lazo cerrado.}
\end{figure}
Entonces se dirá que el sistema está bien planteado si:
\begin{equation}
I-\hat { K }(\infty)P(\infty) \textrm{es invertible}.
\end{equation}
\\De esta manera, se puede decir que un sistema es internamente estable si, y solo sí:\\
a)El sistema está bien planteado\\
b)$det(I-\hat { K }(\infty)P(\infty))$ no tiene ceros en la parte cerrada derecha del plano.\\

O dicho de otra forma, el sistema es internamente estable si:\\
i) El número de polos en la parte derecha del plano de $P(s)\hat{K}(s)$ es igual a la suma de los polos en la parte derecha del plano de $P(s)$ y de $\hat{K}(s)$.\\
ii)${I-\hat { K }(\infty)P(\infty)}^{-1}$ es estable.

\section{Control con $\mathcal{H}_{2}$ y $\mathcal{H}_{\infty}$}
De la misma, forma, una vez analizadas las normas de $\mathcal{H}_{2}$ y $\mathcal{H}_{\infty}$, lo que se busca es reducir la magnitud de dichas normas, como se muestra en la siguiente figura:
\begin{figure}[H] 
    \centering
    \label{fig6}
\includegraphics[scale=1]{f.png} 
    \caption{Diagramas de Bode del sistema de la figura \ref{fig3}, una vez aplicado un control $\mathcal{H}_{2}$ y un $\mathcal{H}_{\infty}$ .}
\end{figure}
\appendix
\chapter{Bibliografía}
\begin{itemize}
\item Zhou, K., \& Doyle, J. (1998).
\\ Essentials of robust control. 
\\ Upper Saddle River, N.J.: Prentice Hall.
\\ Recuperado de \url{https://es.slideshare.net/WenChihPei/essentials-of-robust-control}

\item Norma vectorial. (2019).\\
 Recuperado de \url{https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norma_vectorial}

\item Espacio de Hilbert. (2019)\\
Recuperado de \url{https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Espacio_de_Hilbert}

\item Norma Vectorial. (2019)\\
Recuperado de \url{https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norma_vectorial}

\item Zaballa, I. (2014). Analisis matricial, aplicado y ampliación de métodos numéricos.\\
Recuperado de \url{http://www.ehu.eus/izaballa/Ana_Matr/Apuntes/lec2.pdf}

\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You have a `{` on line 176 unpaired.

Comment: Your code compiles perfectly, once your images are replaced by others. Which compilation engine do you use?

Comment: Have you tried deleting all aux files before recompiling? On my system, your code compiles fine once I add the document class option `demo` (since I don't have access to the graphics files `a.png`, `b.png`, etc thru `h.png`). The only thing I would recommend changing is inserting a `\newpage` directive both before and after `\tableofcontents`.

Comment: Is this issue solved for you? How?